# What is `First rollback`?

Tags: feature-request

What is `Cleanup Badges` and what is the meaning of that.

Can Any one Explain in detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find here a list of [all SO badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397/224252) explained.
The cleanup badge is awarded when you rollback to a previous version of a post. (question or answer.)

[image: Rollback buttons]